# Why is my IBOutLet connected to another project's storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have two projects. And there are two class which has the same name in each project. And these two classes have an iboutlet which has the same name. If i open only one project, it's normal. But if i open both, one of my iboutlet is connected to view in other project's storyboard.

Is this a bug of xcode?

Comment: I have had this problem in the past; restarting Xcode and clearing derived data sometimes fixed it (and sometimes didn't). I learned that I shouldn't copy my entire project to do versioning and discovered source control. Anyway, 3-letter naming convention should solve this http://nshipster.com/namespacing/

Comment: Did you have another project open while you were doing this? Sometimes it connects by accident. Another issue I am finding with Xcode 6 is that it sometimes creates an item in other projects if more than 1 is open. Try closing all the projects with the exception of your current one.